# Task/Resource Manager Memory Usage Accuracy Ubuntu 18

Tags: memory-usage, top, htop

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04LTS (8GB RAM) and I noticed how the Gnome task manager, the "top" and "htop" applications give me 3 considerably different memory usage figures. For instance, right now:

- System Monitor (GUI app): 2.9GB used
- top (terminal app): 3.7GB used
- htop (terminal app): 4.0GB used

My questions are: Which one is more accurate? And why does each app give me significantly different figures?

Thanks!